# How can I find the specific function causing l3 stalls?

Tags: rust, profiling, perf

I'm optimizing a program (in Rust). On a small test input, I see that the program runs relatively quickly, and spends almost no time stalled on cache misses. (Using `perf` on linux)

```
          cycle_activity.stalls_l1d_miss:      50,833,346
           cycle_activity.stalls_l3_miss:       9,958,752
                                  cycles:   3,850,988,364
                            instructions:   9,563,267,270
```

On a large input, I see that the program runs much slower, and spends significant amount of time stalled on cache misses. (Note that the instruction count is almost identical.)

```
          cycle_activity.stalls_l1d_miss:   2,142,605,809
           cycle_activity.stalls_l3_miss:   1,845,486,382
                                  cycles:   6,097,683,006
                            instructions:   9,357,073,844
```

For those approximately `2,000,000,000` cycles spent stalled on l3 access, I'd like to know which accesses in my code are causing them, at any granularity possible (function / instruction pointer / callstack). In terms of the source code, I know of several locations that I suspect might be contributing, but I don't know how to figure out exactly which is the issue. How can I find this? Is it possible with `perf`, maybe using PEBS? Should I use another tool (e.g. valgrind)?

Note, I've tried using `perf record` + `perf report`, but looking at the top slow instructions didn't give me an answer, and also that mixes all sources of slowness (e.g. branches), whereas here I want to focus on specifically l3 stalls.

Also note that my program has a significant amount of setup code that I'd like to exclude from profiling if possible.

Comment: Did you try `perf record -e cycle_activity.stalls_l3_miss` to record samples in functions that often stall on L3 misses?  You can `perf record` on events other than `cycles`.

Comment: that seems to do the trick! Do you happen to know where this filtering aspect is documented? I don't see it mentioned in `man perf record` :(

Comment: It's not "filtering", it's recording an entirely different event, other than the default `cycles` (which on Intel maps to `cpu_clk_unhalted.thread` or something similar, I think).  `-e` / `--event` is the first option documented in the man page.  https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-record.1.html .  The event name is the same one you're using with `perf stat -e`.  `perf list` shows the available events on your hardware.